# IEEE-format author line when one author is "Senior Member" and another is unaffiliated with IEEE

Tags: formatting, ieee

I will shortly be submitting a paper to an IEEE-formatted journal. I am not affiliated with the IEEE, while my co-author is.

Currently, the author line reads like (made-up author names)

> Fred Boggs, Bob Fredds, *Senior Member, IEEE*

One of the reviewers expresses concern that **"it is unclear if the first author is IEEE-affiliated"** (no, I am not). How should I format this? I have been unable to find references in standard IEEE template files. Should I sign up for IEEE just to have something to write next to my name?

Comment: On one paper i've seen, the primary author was listed as a IEEE Fellow and the other was listed as a Jolly Good Fellow.... so I'd say don't overthink this.

Comment: I would use a semicolon in place f tye first comma, and then let the copy editor actually fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest asking the journal editor.  This seems more like a question of journal style than actual content, and the editor should be able to help with that.

I assume there is a tradition or convention that IEEE members are identified as such.  Otherwise, I don't know why you would include this information at all; I don't see why a reader would care.

Comment: I have always assumed that it is a type of brand-awareness that IEEE encourages in its publications: IEEE templates assume that authors will want to state "Fellow, IEEE" next to their names.

Answer (score 4):

The example you have given in your question is correct.

> Fred Boggs, Bob Fredds, *Senior Member, IEEE*

Here, Fred Boggs is not a member, while Bob Fredds is a *Senior Member.* This is the exact way you should format the author line in this example.

In general, if you are not an IEEE member, you do not list anything next to your name in the author line for any papers you submit to IEEE journals: you should only list the membership grade next to your co-author's names if they are IEEE members.

> Should I sign up for IEEE just to have something to write next to my name?

You should not join IEEE just to have something to write next to your name in the author line of any papers you submit to IEEE journals (for more information on IEEE membership benefits, you may find [this site](http://www.ieee.org/membership_services/index.html) helpful).

Answer (score 3):

Your reviewer is overreaching beyond their duties. S/he is not a copy editor and it is not their place to check the affiliations, it is IEEE's.

Plus it is obvious because it does not say Senior member **s**, only says Senior Member so singular membership is implied. I would hope that they paid more attention to your article than this nonsense which is around for at least two decades that should be quite familiar to any in this business unless it is a freshman getting warmed up with reviewing papers.